# Trying to stop my program when two lines are empty using fgets()

Tags: c, fgets, lines

Basically I'm making a short program that reads two lines and, if they are different, it will write both of them. If thery are the same sentences, the program shall write only one sentence. Program should stop when it encounters two empty lines. And that's a problem. I can't figure out how to do it. I've already tried to use strcmp() function but that didn't work either. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char sent1[6000], sent2[6000];

    while(1){

    fgets(sent1, sizeof(sent1), stdin);
    fgets(sent2, sizeof(sent2), stdin);

    if(strcmp(sent1, sent2)!=0)
        printf("%s%s", sent1, sent2);
    else
        printf("%s", sent1);

    if((sent1[0] == '/0') && (sent2[0] == '/0'))
        break;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lines are not empty because [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) would read in the newlines (`'\n'`). So you'd need to check for the newline charater instead.

```
if((sent1[0] == '\n') && (sent2[0] == '\n'))
    break;
```

Not so relevant anymore, but your comparison is wrong because the null character is `'\0'`, not `'/0'`.

As said before, `fgets()` would read in the newline character if there's space in the buffer. In your case, since you're comparing them, you need to be aware of that. Probably needs to strip out the newline character too. e.g.,

```
char *p;
if ((p = strchr(sent1, '\n')) != NULL)
    *p = '\0';
```

(same with `sent2` as well)

Another case to consider is what if the `fgets()` calls fail. You need to check their return value for failures. `fgets()` returns NULL on failure.

Comment: '/0' insted of '\0' was a typo :D. Anyways thanks for your help! Changing  if((sent1[0] == '\0') && (sent2[0] == '\0')) into if((sent1[0] == '\n') && (sent2[0] == '\n')) worked.

Comment: You're welcome! While it worked for you, keep in mind about the things mentioned in the answer. You need to be aware of *when* it might fail too. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) reads in a line including the new line character. So if your file contains empty lines, then such a line may have a `'\n'` at position `0`, not a `'\0'`.

Try:

```
if( ((sent1[0] == '\0') || (sent1[0] == '\n'))
   && ((sent1[0] == '\0') || (sent1[0] == '\n')) )
```

Further, note that you should check the return value of `fgets`, which is `NULL` if end of file has been reached. In such a case, `sent1` or `sent2` would not be altered any more, and you might run into an infinite loop.